# ASP.NET Website not responding

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, asp.net

I am setting with my server tech, trying to figure out what is going on here.

When I try to access my site through a browser, my site hangs indefinately.
It does not respond with anything, not even after 15 minutes!

The application pool has been restarted, the website has been restarted. Doesn't helpt at all.

It happened during an upload.

A backup has been loaded and the problem is still the same

It is a very urgent matter, I hope someone can help me!

I think we are on a IIS 6 on a Windows 2003 Server. (Remote hosted, with a tech, who has no idea what the issue is as well, so I am trying to find the solution alogn with him).

Any suggestions are VERY appriciated.

Comment: Alright, if somebody wants it, I will send $50 over paypal to the one that solves this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to find your IIS logs, and see if they indicate what is going on while you are trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

The second step (after Brent's IIS logs idea) might be to get [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) on the server and do some monitoring. Shut down IIS, start it back up and then turn on monitoring right before you hit the site -- look for "ACCESS DENIED" or non-success type events.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by having the server guy deleting the website and create it in the IIS once again.

If anyone ever tries this, that is a brute force way to solve it.

Thanks for the contributions.